# SharePoint FBA and Custom data - SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, user-profile, forms-authentication

I'm not sure I'm doing this in the right way, but I was hoping someone here could guide me.

I have an application that I'm creating, allows users to create accounts, login, view their billing history, etc.

I have provisioned FBA on the web application, and am using the SharePoint login control.
Using this - 
http://www.chapmanconsulting.ca/post/2010/05/08/Using-a-Custom-ASPNET-Form-for-SharePoint-2010-FBA.aspx

I have 5 other fields that need to be associated with the user ID. The regasp_sql application creates user and table roles in my custom database, I can populate it via the registration control.

Following are the fields that I see in the custom database that was created when I provisioned FBA -

User_ID
Password
Role

I also need - 
account_id
firstname
lastname

and the account_id will be a foreign key to a separate table

Am I doing this right? How do I add the extra column to the user profile table?

Also, when the user registers, there are fields that I'll need to have them fill out, how/where do I put those? The out of the box registration control doesn't have some of these fields.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score -1):

try the new ASP.Net Identity System.
[Introduction to ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)
and
Customizing User's Profile to add new fields in brand new database table [here](http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customizing-users-profile-to-add-new.html)